# CNN - upsampling backprop gradients across average-pooling layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

How to up-sample gradients, during back-propagation, across an average-pooling layer?

**For this purpose**, let

$$
A^{[l]} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}; \quad P^{[l]} = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{21} + a_{22}}{4} & \frac{a_{12} + a_{13} + a_{22} + a_{23}}{4} \\
\frac{a_{21} + a_{22} + a_{31} + a_{32}}{4} & \frac{a_{22} + a_{23} + a_{32} + a_{33}}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}P^{[l]}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} & \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} & \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where, $A^{[l]}$ is the activation of layer-$l$ , and $P^{[l]}$ is the matrix obtained after average-pooling $A^{[l]}$ using a $2 \times 2$ pooling window, and $J$ is the cost function.

Given this, how to compute $\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}A^{[l]}}$?

- ([Source](https://jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/#pooling-layer)) says, "*the error is multiplied by $\frac{1}{2×2}$ and assigned to the whole pooling block (all units get this same value).*" $\rightarrow$ then what would be the gradient $\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}a_{22}}$, which is a member of all the pooling blocks.
- ([Source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/223869/248568)) the question mentions the up-sampling strategy, but doesn't mention what $\beta$ is.
- ([Source](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork/)) says, "*if we have mean pooling then upsample simply uniformly distributes the error for a single pooling unit among the units which feed into it in the previous layer.*" $\rightarrow$ which is still vague.
- ([Source](https://zzutk.github.io/docs/reports/2016.10%20-%20Derivation%20of%20Backpropagation%20in%20Convolutional%20Neural%20Network%20(CNN).pdf)) Zhang, Zhifei. "Derivation of backpropagation in convolutional neural network (cnn)." University of Tennessee, Knoxville, TN (2016). $\rightarrow$ `pg.4, eq.32` results in the following up-sampled gradients
  $$
  \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}A^{[l]}} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} & \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} & \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} \\
  \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} & \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} & \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} \\
  \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} & \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} & \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}}  \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
  $$
  **Is this correct? And, if it is, then is there a mathematical basis for why the gradients are up-sampled this way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not right. When the pool windows overlap, derivatives must be added. This is not explicitly stated in Sources 1-3. I couldn't see it in Source 4 as well but I'm not too sure as the document is long.

Addition happens simply because of the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{ij}}=\sum_{m,n}\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{mn}}\frac{\partial p_{mn}}{\partial a_{ij}}$$

For example, for $a_{12}$, we'll have

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{12}}&
=\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{11}}\frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{12}}
+\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{12}}\frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{12}}
+\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{21}}\frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{12}}
+\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{22}}\frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{12}}\\
&=\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{11}}\frac{1}{4}
+\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{12}}\frac{1}{4}
+\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{21}}0
+\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{22}}0\\
&=\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{11}}\frac{1}{4}
+\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{12}}\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}$$

It doesn't matter if this is pooling, upsampling/downsampling etc. We have a bunch of numbers $a_{ij}$, we transform and calculate a bunch of another numbers $p_{mn}$ and propagate until the loss is calculated. This should be treated like a usual transformation in order to comply with the mathematics.

Comment: how to obtain this summation (i.e., $\frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{ij}}=\sum_{m,n}\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_{mn}}\frac{\partial p_{mn}}{\partial a_{ij}}$) using matrix-calculus?

Comment: I don't know which way would be best, but it needs reshaping since the second multiplicand is a 4d tensor with indices m,n,i,j. If you flatten dJ/dp (row-major) and construct another matrix with shape 4x9 where each entry holds the derivative of dP/dA (both flattened), then you can form a matrix mult, (dJ/dP) x (dP/dA).

Comment: @gunes- I thought of the exact same method, and posted it as an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/565092/248568).

Answer (score 2):

> This is based on gunes's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/565064/248568) above.

We can vectorize all the matrices as follows:

$$
\mathrm{vec}(A^{[l]}) = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} \\
a_{21} \\
a_{31} \\
a_{12} \\
a_{22} \\
a_{32} \\
a_{13} \\
a_{23} \\
a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}; \qquad \mathrm{vec}(P^{[l]}) = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} \\
p_{21} \\
p_{12} \\
p_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
\qquad \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}\{\mathrm{vec}(P^{[l]})\}} =  \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} &
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} &
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} &
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}}
\end{bmatrix} \qquad\text{eq.1}
$$

then compute the gradient $\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}A^{[l]}}$, as follows:

> Note: I'm using the numerator-layout, so, the derivatives are technically Jacobians.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}\{\mathrm{vec}(A^{[l]})\}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}\{\mathrm{vec}(P^{[l]})\}} \frac{\mathrm{d}\{\mathrm{vec}(P^{[l]})\}}{\mathrm{d}\{\mathrm{vec}(A^{[l]})\}}  \qquad\text{eq.2}\\
$$

here,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\{\mathrm{vec}(P^{[l]})\}}{\mathrm{d}\{\mathrm{vec}(A^{[l]})\}} & = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a_{11}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{21}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{31}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{12}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{22}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{32}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{13}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{23}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{33}}
\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} \\
p_{21} \\
p_{12} \\
p_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{11}} & \frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{21}} & \frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{31}} & \frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{12}} & \frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{22}} & \frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{32}} & \frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{13}} & \frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{23}} & \frac{\partial p_{11}}{\partial a_{33}} \\
\frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{11}} & \frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{21}} & \frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{31}} & \frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{12}} & \frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{22}} & \frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{32}} & \frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{13}} & \frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{23}} & \frac{\partial p_{21}}{\partial a_{33}} \\
\frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{11}} & \frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{21}} & \frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{31}} & \frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{12}} & \frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{22}} & \frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{32}} & \frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{13}} & \frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{23}} & \frac{\partial p_{12}}{\partial a_{33}} \\
\frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{11}} & \frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{21}} & \frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{31}} & \frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{12}} & \frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{22}} & \frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{32}} & \frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{13}} & \frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{23}} & \frac{\partial p_{22}}{\partial a_{33}} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}  \qquad\text{eq.3}
\end{align}
$$

from eq.1, eq.2, and eq.3, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}\{\mathrm{vec}(A^{[l]})\}} & = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{11}} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{21}} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{31}} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{12}} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{22}} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{32}} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{13}} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{23}} & \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{33}} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} \\ 
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}}\biggr) \\ 
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} \\ 
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}}\biggr) \\ 
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}}\biggr) \\
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}}\biggr) \\
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} \\
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}}\biggr) \\
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}} \\
\end{bmatrix}^\intercal
\end{align}
$$

And, reshaping the above matrix, we get

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}A^{[l]}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} &
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}}\biggr) & 
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} \\ 
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}}\biggr) & 
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{11}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}}\biggr) &
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{21}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}}\biggr) \\
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} &
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{12}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}}\biggr) &
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}J}{\mathrm{d}p_{22}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: (+1) thanks for materializing it :)